# about the pthread_cond_wait?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
...
    volatile int i_lines_completed;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    q265_pthread_cond_t cv;
...
}q265_picture_t;
void q265_frame_cond_broadcast( q265_picture_t *frame, int i_lines_completed )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &frame->mutex );
    frame->i_lines_completed = i_lines_completed;
    pthread_cond_broadcast( &frame->cv );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &frame->mutex );
}
void q265_frame_cond_wait( q265_picture_t *frame, int i_lines_completed )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &frame->mutex );
    while( frame->i_lines_completed < i_lines_completed )
        pthread_cond_wait( &frame->cv, &frame->mutex );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &frame->mutex );
}
```

The use case is:

More than one thread could call `q265_frame_cond_wait`  to request that the frame have the required `i_lines_completed` while there is only one thread call the `q265_frame_cond_broadcast` to broadcast the `i_lines_completed`.

The question is:

Is it valid that several threads call the `q265_frame_cond_wait` synchronously？

When the certain thread call the `q265_frame_cond_broadcast`,

- Will all the waiting threads get the mutex synchronously?
- Or they must compete to get the mutex?

Another problem:
But is it right that two pthread_cond_t share only one mutex? For example, the following code, the two pthread_cond_t is_fill and is_empty share the only one mutex, and threads will possibly call q265_framelist_cond_wait0 and q265_framelist_cond_wait1 synchronously.

```
typedef struct {
...
    volatile int i_size;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    q265_pthread_cond_t is_fill, is_empty;
...
}q265_picture_list_t;
void q265_framelist_cond_wait0( q265_picture_list_t *framelist)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &framelist->mutex );
    while( framelist->i_size <= 0)
        pthread_cond_wait( &framelist->is_fill, &framelist->mutex );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &framelist->mutex );
}
void q265_framelist_cond_wait1( q265_picture_list_t *framelist)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &framelist->mutex );
    while( framelist->i_size == max_size)
        pthread_cond_wait( &framelist->is_empty, &framelist->mutex );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &framelist->mutex );
}
```

Comment: Yes if you read about `pthread_cond_broadcast` it is implied that multiple threads can wait on one condition. The mutex will be unlocked while the threads are in `pthread_cond_wait` so while they wait there there is no issue. Afterwards and before that they will have to wait for each other to release the mutex

Answer (score 2):

> The question is: Is it valid that several threads call the q265_frame_cond_wait synchronously

Multiple threads can call `q265_frame_cond_wait`, there is no race condition.

> `q265_frame_cond_broadcast`, will all the waiting thread get the mutex synchronously?

`pthread_cond_broadcast` wakes up all threads currently waiting on the condition variable. Only one thread can lock a mutex at a time, so that these woken up threads queue up on locking the mutex.

> Or they must compete to get the mutex?

Conceptually yes, `pthread_cond_wait` has to lock the mutex on return. And this is known as [thundering herd problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem).

Linux solves this problem by moving the queue of waiters on the condition variable to the queue of waiters on the mutex to avoid waking up threads that would then immediately be blocked on the mutex. This is known as *wait morphing*.